# Use PHP to extract data from MariaDB and generate hierarchical JSON - tree view of folders

Tags: php, json, mariadb

How to use PHP to dynamically create a hierarchical JSON from two MariaDB tables.
The JSON will be used to render a tree view of folders via JavaScript in a web page.

I found the JavaScript [library](https://www.cssscript.com/folder-tree-json/) to render the tree, but I don't know what SQL queries to use and how to combine them in PHP to generate the JSON.

In this example there are some books, which are part of some folders.
The folders are "arranged" hierarchical (with parent, respectively sub-folders), and each folder name is unique in all the folder tree.

Table Books:

```
id, name, folder, author, description
1, Book 0, , foo, bar
2, Book 1, Folder 1, foo, bar
3, Book 2, Folder 1, foo, bar
4, Book 3, Folder 2, foo, bar
5, Book 4, Folder 2, foo, bar
6, Book 5, Subfolder 1.1, foo, bar
7, Book 6, Subfolder 1.2, foo, bar
8, Book 7, Subfolder 1.1.1, foo, bar
9, Book 8, Subfolder 1.1.2, foo, bar
10, Book 9, Subfolder 1.1.1.1, foo, bar
```

Table Folders:

```
id, name, parent
1, Folder 1,
2, Folder 2,
3, Subfolder 1.1, Folder 1
4, Subfolder 1.2, Folder 1
5, Subfolder 1.1.1, Subfolder 1.1
6, Subfolder 1.1.2, Subfolder 1.1
7, Subfolder 1.1.1.1, Subfolder 1.1.1
```

Expected JSON Tree:

```
var structure = [{
  type: Tree.FOLDER,
  name: 'Tree',
  children: [{
      name: 'Book 0'
    }, {
      type: Tree.FOLDER,
      name: 'Folder 1',
      children: [{
          name: 'Book 1'
        }, {
          name: 'Book 2'
        }, {
          type: Tree.FOLDER,
          name: 'Subfolder 1.1',
          children: [{
              name: 'Book 5'
            }, {
              type: Tree.FOLDER,
              name: 'Subfolder 1.1.1',
              children: [{
                 name: 'Book 7'
                }, {
                  type: Tree.FOLDER,
                  name: 'Subfolder 1.1.1.1',
                  children: [{
                     name: 'Book 9'
                    }]
                }]
            }, {
              type: Tree.FOLDER,
              name: 'Subfolder 1.1.2',
              children: [{
                 name: 'Book 8'
                }]
            }]
        }, {
          type: Tree.FOLDER,
          name: 'Subfolder 1.2',
          children: [{
              name: 'Book 6'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
      type: Tree.FOLDER,
      name: 'Folder 2',
      children: [{
          name: 'Book 3'
        }, {
          name: 'Book 4'
        }]
    }]
}];
```

Tree Preview:

[image: tree preview]

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 5.5.68-MariaDB, but it can be upgraded to a higher version if needed.

Comment: To get the data out of MySQL, you might need a [CTE to handle recursion](https://cjhaas.com/2019/10/25/mysql-recursive-cte/) at the database level. Or you can possibly select everything from two tables and write a recursive PHP file that generates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I found what I was looking for.

The result of the function is a JSON that can be used to render a tree of folders.
Probably there are better methods to generate the JSON tree, but this is good enough for me. (solved my problem)

INFO: The files 'tree.js' and 'tree.css' are from '[Simple Folder Tree With JSON And JavaScript](https://www.cssscript.com/folder-tree-json/)'

```
<?php
$Conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

//Escape user data before SQL query
function e($input) {
    global $Conn;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($Conn, $input);
}

function tree($current_parent) {
    global $Conn;
    $str="";

    $folders = $Conn->query("SELECT `name` FROM `folders` WHERE `parent`='". e($current_parent) ."' ORDER BY `name` ASC;");
    $folders_length = $folders->num_rows;

    for($i=0; $i<$folders_length; $i++) {
        $folders_row = $folders->fetch_assoc();
        $str .= "{";
        $str .= "type: Tree.FOLDER,";
        $str .= "name: '". $folders_row['name'] ."',";
        $str .= "children: [";

        $str .= tree($folders_row['name']);

        $str .= "]";
        $str .= ($i != ($folders_length-1)) ? "}," : "}";
    }

    $books = $Conn->query("SELECT `name` FROM `books` WHERE `folder`='". e($current_parent) ."' ORDER BY `name` ASC;");
    $books_length = $books->num_rows;

    for($j=0; $j<$books_length; $j++) {
        if(($i>0)&&($j==0)){
            $str .= ",";
        }
        $books_row = $books->fetch_assoc();
        $str .= "{";
        $str .= "name: '". $books_row['name'] ."'";
        $str .= ($j != ($books_length-1)) ? "}," : "}";
    }

    return $str;
}
?>

<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="html/css/tree.css">
<SCRIPT SRC="html/js/tree.js"></SCRIPT>
<BR>
<DIV ID="tree"></DIV>
<SCRIPT>
/* globals Tree */
'use strict';

var tree = new Tree(document.getElementById('tree'), {
  navigate: true // allow navigate with ArrowUp and ArrowDown
});

var structure = <?php echo "[". tree("") ."]"; ?>;
tree.json(structure);
</SCRIPT>
```